# Is it possible to stop a Pokemon evolving via trade in Gen 1?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

If I level up a Pokemon and it's about to evolve, I can hold down B to stop it.
What about if I trade Kadabra, Graveler, Machoke or Haunter? Can I stop them from evolving when I trade them somehow?
I tried it just now and held down B, and they seemed to evolve anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

> In Gen 1, the only way to stop a Pokemon from evolving was by pressing B. However, evolution stones and trading trumped pressing the B button.

According to [Gamefaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/gameboy/367023-pokemon-red-version/answers/594367-can-you-cancel-trade-evolutions-in-rby) and personal experience.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, it makes sense with the stones because you only use them when you choose to. Bit of a shame about the trading situation

Comment: @pinckerman yes, but they could have been coded not to evolve or have a cancel button, it was a choice. And the sense would be if you wanted to give someone the unevolved pokemon.

Comment: @pinckerman well, I wanted to trade over a Kadabra without evolving it yesterday and presumably I'm not the only one. I'm surprised they didn't put in the same code that handles evolution after battles

Comment: @pinckerman the trade was an action I made. The evolution via the trade was something I ran into, having forgotten about it at that point. I wouldn't run into evolution by stone by accident

Comment: This, presumably, is why they added the Everstone item in the second generation - it will prevent even a traded Pokémon from evolving. (Unfortunately the item became bugged in later generations!)

Comment: @Showsni Can you point me to more info on that? Sounds like it might be possible to have some fun with it.

Comment: @EgorHans https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Everstone has most info on it. There's also an article here: https://screenrant.com/pookemon-diamond-pearl-trade-bad-mindy-haunter-everstone/ about a particular in game trade for a Haunter...

Comment: @Showsni Sounds like the glitches are nothing useful. Also no clue if the Kadabra oddity is intentional or not.